# IOS Focus on a disabled texfield

Tags: ios

I created 50 text fields array in a scrollview but I've disabled it to prevent user input. I want it to auto scroll to the specific text field example from text field 01 to 40 and then maybe from text field 40 back to 10 with a press of a button. I manage to do it with the following code:

```
//button pressed
UITextField *textfield = (UITextField *)[textfieldArray objectAtIndex:40];  
textfield.enabled = YES;  
[textfield becomeFirstResponder];  
textfield.enabled = NO;
```

I enabling it back to force the focus and then disabling it. Using the IOS simulator it works and no keyboard pop up but I not sure whether this is the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use `[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect) animated:(BOOL)]` method

For example:

```
CGRect rect = textField.frame;
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible: rect animated:YES];
```